# How to search a column and return the value in the next column with specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that contains columns and multiple sheets. I want to copy column A from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Then once I've copied column A, I want column B from Sheet2 to have a specific value (in this case, "D") adjacent to each filled cell in A. I am only stuck with the code below.

Example:

Sheet1 contains:

```
Column A      B      C
       Arthur 1      34
       Bertha 2      35
```

Sheet2 must have:

```
Column A      B
       Arthur "D"
       Bertha "D"
```

Stuck with code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Copy ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").Columns("A")
```

Comment: FYI: the problem with you code lies in "ActiveCell".

As a good programming practice, try to avoid use of ActiveCell, ActiveSheet in macros. They can be a headache in big macros.

If you must, just Activate the concerned cell before using those objects.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wsI = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = Sheets("Sheet2")

    wsI.Columns(1).Copy wsO.Columns(1)

    lRow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wsO.Range("B1:B" & lRow).Value = "D"
End Sub
```

Comment: `Is this what you are trying` I think so :)